# How an I add a new review (preset on query params) in Google Places Review Form

Tags: google-places-api, google-places, google-reviews

I need to preset in the query params, the value of the comment and rating, i tried many things but I couldn't do it.

I need to set something like this:

**comment** => This is my favorite place

**rating** => 4 stars

**Final URL** => https://search.google.com/local/writereview?placeid=ChIJp1wnA_Kwj4ARujtkQxLf78E&comment=this%20is%20my%20favorite%20place&rating=4

A couple of years ago, there were an API but now is obsolete. Somebody knows how can i pass this query params in the URL and what params are enabled?

[Google Review Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqeHI.jpg)